# Replace snapshot image (taken by iOS when app goes to BG) when app resumes

Tags: ios

I need to hide/replace the screenshot image taken by iOS when app goes to background.
The purpose is to display different image(similar to splash screen) instead of screenshot taken by iOS.
Also i cannot add any screen on window when app goes to background because that will cause showing of the added screen every time when app resumes.

What i want is in some circumstance the should not show the screenshot taken by iOS when app resumes and instead of that i should be able to show different splash screen.

Thanks
Rohit